# Traverse the DOM and get IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

With the following HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="a">
        <a href=# id="a!1">qq</a>
        <a href=# id="a!3">qw</a>
        <a href=# id="a!2">qe</a> 
    </div>
    <div id="b">
        <a href=# id="b!1">qa</a>
        <a href=# id="b!2">qs</a>
        <a href=# id="b!3">qd</a> 
    </div>
    <div id="c">
        <a href=# id="c!1">qz</a>
        <a href=# id="c!2">qx</a>
        <a href=# id="c!3">qc</a>
        <a href=# id="c!4">qv</a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get a list of all the IDs:
a, a!1, a!3, a!2, b, b!1, b!2, b!3, c, c!1, c!2, c!3, c!4

The following code kind of does that:

```
 var arr = $("#main > div").map(function() {
     return this.id
 });
 var aa = (arr.get().join(","));
 alert(aa);
```

but the alert only gives me" "a,b,c"

Is there a better way to do this that I may be missing so it will transverse the DOM of a specific container ID and pass back all the child IDs of all the elements in the container?

Comment: I'm not a jQuery user, but I assume you might be able to use `#main > div, #main > div > *` or at least `#main > div, #main > div > a` since jQuery tries to simulate CSS selectors.

Comment: Strings, including IDs, containing exclamation marks are not legal identifiers in JavaScript. If you try to access your ID by name in jQuery, it will return nothing. Try `$('#a!2')` in the console and it returns an empty result (although the DOM method `document.getElementById("a!1")1 will return a value).

Comment: @Robusto do you have a source for that? I've never heard of this. AFAIK you can even use any string as an object key.

Comment: @Dodekeract: It's true that you can use any string as an object member name, but it can't be accessed in dot notation, only bracket notation. In other words, for object `foo`, `foo.a!1` is illegal and throws a syntax error, while `foo["a!1"]` will work fine. And if you write a statement like `var a!1 = 1` in JavaScript will give you a syntax error. My point is only that using things like operators in JS identifiers is a bad habit to get into; even if it may sometimes work, it's bound to bite you in the ass sooner or later.

Comment: Solution that I went with:

`var arr = $("#main div, #main a").map(function() { return this.id
});
var aa = (arr.get().join(","));
alert(aa);`

Answer (score 4):

Use css selectors in JQuery to iterate through all, instead of **direct** children:

```js
$(function(){
    $('#main *').each(function (){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(id);
        $('#main').append("<br /> -"+id);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    <div id="a">
        <a href=# id="a!1">qq</a>
        <a href=# id="a!3">qw</a>
        <a href=# id="a!2">qe</a> 
    </div>
    <div id="b">
        <a href=# id="b!1">qa</a>
        <a href=# id="b!2">qs</a>
        <a href=# id="b!3">qd</a> 
    </div>
    <div id="c">
        <a href=# id="c!1">qz</a>
        <a href=# id="c!2">qx</a>
        <a href=# id="c!3">qc</a>
        <a href=# id="c!4">qv</a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ran the code snippet in page, the problem is that it kind of worked...
It displayed all the anchors, but displayed the html() not the id() attribute and only did so for the anchors, not the child divs.

Comment: @met00, Yes, thats because the `ID`s in the snippet were shown in the **Browser Console** I changed it to it is displayed in the snippet, give it a try.

Comment: my error... I'm adding this to my toolbox for when I need to do something more complex. The application allows a user to build a page by dropping components into a container and then being able to drag the components around. In this case there is a master container, each which can have a child container and then within that child container a series of links. Tightly controlled format. Your solution will work if I ever need to go to a more "less controlled" environment.

Answer (score 2):

Just do

```
var arr = $("#main > div, #main > div > a").map(function() {
 return this.id
});
```

Your current code gives the id of direct children of `#main` but not of `a`

Answer (score 1):

Just add anchors to query:

```
$("#main div, #main a")
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMWGKW?editors=101)

Answer (score 1):

```
var ids = []
$("a").each(function(){
  ids.push($(this).attr("id"))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var total_id='';
   $('#main *').each(function(){
   total_id+=$(this).attr('id')+',';
})
console.log(total_id);
```

Please try this.